# URL Amigavel não permite acessar a index do site

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável

Olá, tenho a seguinte código no `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```

Porem quando tento acessar a pagina principal `site.com` ele diz que não é possível acessar.

index.php

```
<body>
    <?php
        require 'config/tratarUrl.php';
        include $pag;
    ?>
</body>
```

tratarUrl.php

```
if(file_exists(DIR_PAGES.$url[0].'.php'))
{
    $pag = DIR_PAGES.$url[0].'.php';
}
```

Comment: é wordpress? acho que essa informação depende de como sua index trabalha para manipular os dados recebidos

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA, L]` começa corrigindo isso.

Comment: @DaniloD Eu uso Xampp para abrir o site.

Answer (score 0):

acredito que o código a seguir vai funcionar para você

```
# BEGIN
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END
```

mas lembrando, tudo depende de como sua aplicação trabalha

Comment: Mesmo coisa, quando tento acessar aparece o erro `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Comment: tem como colocar o código da sua index?

Comment: Já editei a pergunta.